# php output from mysql inconsistent quotes and other punctuation

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I have information from a mysql database that I'm obtaining through php and echoing into a page. I first noticed my problem because I was seeing some \' s in the output as well as some black diamonds with question marks. I did some research and realized 2 things.

1. I designed the tool to enter information to my database poorly because it was including escape characters.
2. I could remedy this by calling stripslashes.

Using strip slashes removed the \ from the output, however the unrecognized characters were still there. I looked into that and realized this was some sort of char encoding problem. But what I don't understand is that I had fields in the database where some 's were escaped (\) and some where they weren't. For example:

Today\'s dish was yesterday's dish.

I don't understand why one single quote would be escaped and one wouldn't. Some other characters that weren't recognized were some double quotes ("), some commas (,) and even some periods (specifically an elipsis ...).

What am I missing?

Additionally, my database is in utf-unicode and just to clarify I have both \' and ' in the same field in some of my database entries. These entries are varchar if that makes a difference.

Let me know if I need to provide any additional information.

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/), [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/) and look into [Magic Quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php).

Comment: I read both articles and I didn't see anything that applied to having 2 ' s treated 2 different ways in a database field. I have looked into Magic Quotes and I tried turning them on and off to no avail.

Comment: Yeah, the different treatment is plain weird, but it's hard to comment on without knowing what *exactly* happened to them.

Comment: Do you know of anyway to standardize them?

Comment: If there's no discernible pattern, the best you can do is probably to use a dictionary/spell checker to fix the existing data. No, that's not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

This is two little pieces of code form `PHP` `.net` pasted together. It uses PDO to talk to the database. This is A LOT better than using stripslashes `msqli_real_escape_string`.

```
<?php
/* Connect to an ODBC database using driver invocation */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    /* Execute a prepared statement by binding PHP variables */
    $calories = 150;
    $colour = 'red';
    $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
        FROM fruit
        WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
    $sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->bindParam(':colour', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
    $sth->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: I am using PDO to communicate with the database and I'm stripping the slashes from the result. The inconsistent slashes are already in the database.